# asp:RangeValidator validates on textChanged in TextBox

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

I have the following `<asp:RangeValidator>`:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxInterestRate" ErrorMessage="Enter value greater than zero!" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="100000" MinimumValue="0.10"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

If the page is loaded for the first time, then the `RangeValidator` works perfectly. But, I have a `Button` in my project, which on clicking, loads the `TextBox` with a certain value (always within the range 0.1 - 100000). Now if I edit the value in the `TextBox` from the keyboard, the `RangeValidator` is popping up the `ErrorMessage` even when the new value/edited value is well within the range.

For example, say the value that came into the `TextBox` on clicking the `Button` is `8.5`. Now, if I change it to `10.25`, the `ErrorMessage` is popping up. What should I do?

I am working on ASP.NET WebForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on [MSDN RangeValidator Control Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt(v=vs.71).aspx). All I needed to do was to add `Type = "Double"` to the statement and it worked perfectly.

`<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxInterestRate" ErrorMessage="Enter value greater than zero!" ForeColor="Red" Type="Double" MaximumValue="100000" MinimumValue="0.10"></asp:RangeValidator>`

The available `DataTypes` are:

`Currency, Date, Double, Integer, String`